# Discord.py verify command that auto roles

Tags: python, discord

I am trying to make a verify command that when they type the message it auto roles them the role and Deletes the message after but when I type verify it does nothing at all this is what I got

```
  if message.channel.id == 1099599418551963699:
    if message.content == "verify":
        role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="verified")
        await message.author.add_roles(role)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Verified", description=f"You have been verified", color=0x0000FF)
        await message.author.send(embed=embed)
    await message.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the message using on_message fucntion:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):
    if message.channel.id == 1085634200415248446 and message.content.lower() == "verify":
        role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="verified")
        await message.author.add_roles(role)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Verified", description=f"You have been verified", color=0x0000FF)

        await message.delete()

        await message.author.send(embed=embed)
```

You can also do if the message doesn't say verify then the bot will delete it using a elif statement. Also make sure that you enabled all intents from the dev portal

Hope it helps.

Intents doc - https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html

on_message doc - https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message